# Webdriver Xpath - what is difference between By.Name and By.Xpath?

Tags: java, testing, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I`m trying to use xpath type of parameter in my webdriver script.

However, although this parameter actually selects the same HTML tag:

**By START_BUTTON  = By.xpath(".//*[@name='MyName']");**

as this one

**By START_BUTTON  = By.name("MyName");**

I`m not being able to use the by.xpath in my testing script while the by.name is working fine

Not sure why I`m facing this issue. When tested in Firebug/FirePath the path:
**.//*[@name='MyName']** - points exactly to the same A tag as **By.name("MyName")**;

Thanks

Comment: So what happens when you use that XPath? What errors do you get? Post them. In full. Against what browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: what happens when you use the xpath `//*[@name='MyName']`

Comment: It just can`t find the element: java.lang.Error: Start Button is not visible
 at com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver.slowloading.IsLoaded.whenElementIsVisible(IsLoaded.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had the part of  the code commented which actually caused this.
Sorry for bothering you.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Posting it for reference :

These are the locator strategies which helps to identify an element.

Following strategies are mainly used to identify an element :

- By ID
- By Name
- By Class Name
- By Tag Name
- By Link Text
- By Partial Link Text
- By CSS
- By XPath